# UIRefreshControl does not stick after pulled in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uirefreshcontrol

I am using UIRefreshControl with a UICollectionView. The refreshing works but the view does not stay at the top after pulled (as it does with a uitableview). Is there a way to make this stick or is that only implemented for a UITableViewController?

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
[self.collectionView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
```

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution for this thing?

Comment: Hi, not exactly - I did not find a way with the UIRefreshControl so I created a custom refresh view using a UIView and scroll events.

Answer (score -1):

For me it happens only when I'm trying to update cells before calling `.endRefreshing()`.

So, to fix need first call `.endRefreshing()` and then update cells (`reloadData` and so on).